# Why we need validated ledger in a peer in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Before going to my question please refer [what is validated ledger in hyperledger fabric here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/arch-deep-dive.html#validated-ledger-vledger).

Here my questions are:

1) It is mentioned in the doc that "***if a new peer joins the network, other peers could not transfer the discarded blocks (pertaining to PeerLedger) to the joining peer, nor convince the joining peer of the validity of their vBlocks***".

So while adding a new peer why another peers are sending only validated ledger and why they are not sending peer ledger which consists of both valid and invalid transactions?

2) Validated ledger consists of these following things :

1)  The hash of the previous vBlock.
2)  vBlock number.
3)  An ordered list of all valid transactions committed by the peers since the last vBlock was computed (i.e., list of valid transactions in a corresponding block).
4)  ***The hash of the corresponding block (in PeerLedger) from which the current vBlock is derived.***

Why it is maintaining hash of the corresponding block (in PeerLedger) from which the current vBlock is derived?